# XAudio2 with C#

Tags: c#, xaudio2

I am looking to replace my 32bit DirectSound audio API with XAudio2. Does XAudio2 work with a 64bit C# application? If so, I am not entirely sure how to setup the project to begin using XAudio2. All the examples I have seen online are for C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XAudio2 doesn't support C# directly but you can call it using [SharpDX](http://sharpdx.org/), which is a managed .NET wrapper of DirectX API. [Here](https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX-Samples/tree/master/Desktop/XAudio2) you can find a few samples to get started. Other possibilities that I haven't tried but should work:

- [SlimDX](https://slimdx.org/)
- [CSCore](https://github.com/filoe/cscore)